# Type checking returned class PEP 484

Tags: python, typing, type-hinting

I have a function in python which returns a class instead of an instance.  How do I indicate that the returned value is a subclass of a particular type?

In the following example I set the return value as type, but I would further like to indicate that the type has all of the attributes of BaseClass:

```
from typing import Dict, Any

def class_constructor(name: str, attrs: Dict[str, Any]) -> type
    ConstructedClass = type(name, (BaseClass,), attrs)
    return ConstructedClass

class BaseClass: ...
```

I can't say (...) -> BaseClass since that would indicate an instance of BaseClass rather than BaseClass itself.

To answer my own question, this appears as [python/typing issue #107](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/107).  For now, the best solution is:

```
from typing import Dict, Any

class BaseClass: ...

def class_constructor(name: str, attrs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Callable[Any, BaseClass]
    ConstructedClass = type(name, (BaseClass,), attrs)
    return ConstructedClass
```

If you know your `__init__` signature, you can use that instead of `Any` in `Callable[Any, ...]`.

When support for `Type[T]` is added the solution will be:

```
 from typing import Dict, Any

class BaseClass: ...

def class_constructor(name: str, attrs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Type[BaseClass]
    ConstructedClass = type(name, (BaseClass,), attrs)
    return ConstructedClass
```

Comment: Can you provide a concrete, runnable example that fails to do what you want?

Comment: The support for `Type[T]` is added, both in mypy and PEP 484.

Answer (score -1):

I think you would need to create a new class, used by `BaseClass` solely as a way of tagging it and any descendent classes.

```
 class BaseClassMeta(type):
     pass

 class BaseClass(metaclass=BaseClassMeta):
     ...

 def class_constructor(name: str, attrs: Dict[str, Any]) -> BaseClassMeta
     ConstructedClass = BaseClassMeta(name, (BaseClass,), attrs)
     return ConstructedClass
```

Comment: The resulting class does indeed function appropriately, but it doesn't solve the problem.  `BaseClassMeta(...)` produces a type but `ConstructedClass(...)` produces an object, so the returned type cannot be `BaseClassMeta`.  I can get a little closer to what I need using `-> Callable[[...], BaseClass]` where `...` are the arguments to the `__init__` function (which must share a common interface for all constructed classes for this code to be at all sensible).  At least PyCharm is able to infer the attributes of the `ConstructedClass(...)` object if not the attributes of the returned class.

Comment: Why not? Where are you actually creating an instance of `ConstructedClass`? Both `BaseClass` and `ConstructedClass` are instances of `BaseClassMeta`.

Comment: The return value from the class constructor is indeed an instance of `BaseClassMeta`, but it behaves differently.  That is, `BaseClassMeta(...) -> type` but `ConstructedClass(...) -> object`.  If you say that `class_constructor` returns `BaseClassMeta`, then static analysis on the use of `MyClass = class_constructor(...)` will fail when you later say `obj = MyClass()` since `MyClass` of type `BaseClassMeta` is expecting the same signature as the `type` function.

Comment: You aren't instantiating `ConstructedClass` in `class_constructor`, so I don't see how it is relevant that `ConstructClass(...)` returns something of type `object`. Nothing about `class_constructor` says anything about what `MyClass.__call__` returns.

Comment: The return type of `BaseClassMeta` indicates a promise that the returned value has the properties of `BaseClassMeta`, including the behaviour of its `__call__` method.  Just like a return type of `List[str]` would promise that the `__getitem__` method of the return value would have the signature `(int) -> str` or overloaded `(Slice) -> List[str]`.

Comment: Apparently, the best we can do for now is `-> Callable[Any, BaseClass]`.  For details, see [python/typing issue #107](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/107).